# Error InvalidArgumentException No method is configured Post Request con Lumen 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

Estoy tratando de hacer  un post resquest con Lumen (5.5)
El correrlo me genera el Error:

> InvalidArgumentException No method is configured to handle the
>   CodigoCliente config key

. No entiendo porque está pasando esto. 
Mi código.

```
 $url = "https://test.com";
       // $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
        $response = $client->post($url, [
            'CodigoCliente' => 'ca',
            'FechaCreacion' => '',
            'FechaDocumento' => '',
            'FechaEntrega' => '',
            'Observaciones' => 'Esta es una prueba',
            'TipoPago' => 'Tarjeta',
            'noOrderEcwid' => 304,
            'EstadoImpEcWid' => '0',
            'Email' => 'carlosvanegas@gmail.com',
            'NombreCliente' => 'Carlos Vanegas',
            'countryName' => 'GT',
            'countryCode' => 'GT',
            'city' => 'GT',
            'street' => 'T',
            'stateOrProvinceCode' => 'GT',
            'stateOrProvinceName' => 'GT',
            'phone' => '12345678'
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

- Lumen 5.5
- Guzzle "~5.3|~6.0"

Comment: ¿Qué versón de Guzzle utiliza? por favor añada en su pregunta.

Comment: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0" porque estoy usando Lumen 5.5  y lumen 5.5 porque estoy usando php 7.0.33

Answer (score 2):

Estas enviando mal los datos, debes integrarlo en la llave `body`

```
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => ['header' => 'value']
    'body' => [
        'CodigoCliente' => 'ca',
        'FechaCreacion' => '',
        'FechaDocumento' => '',
        'FechaEntrega' => '',
        ...
    ]
]);
```

Para recibir estos parámetros, solo necesitas una instancia de Request

```
$user = \DB::table('tabla')->create($request->all());
return response()->json($user, 201);
```

Puedes usarlo de esta forma, por que todos los campos de la tabla se llaman igual que los parámetros que envias.

Comment: Si, tienes razón gracias. Pero ahora me marca este error.


(1/1) ClientException
Client error response [url]  https://url/ejempplo/w [status code] 405 [reason phrase] Method Not Allowed

Comment: Ese es problema de la url a la que haces la solicitud

Comment: Bueno, lo que ahora me está fallando es porque me falta un content-type, lo intente hacer asi: $client->getHeader('content-type'); pero no me funcionó

Comment: Si necesitas añador un header, debes mandarlo con la key `headers`, revisa mi respuesta editada

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, en el postman si me funciona pero solo me lanza un mensaje que le tengo validado del lado la funcion request (es la ruta del post) voy a dejar el código abajo.

Comment: Por algùn motivo no està mandando el contentype

Comment: Necesitas mandarlo en json forzosamente? Guzzle lo manda como parámetros

Comment: No,  lo puedo mandar como otro formato. si Guzzle lo manda como parametro, del lado de la tura del  en donde esta el post (cuando hace el insert) como lo pudo recibir ?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta con la edición para recibir datos

Answer (score 0):

**"ERROR": "No Autorizado"** Este mensaje me debe mostrar al no llevar los header, pero ya se los coloqué, este es el código en el request el url del post.

```
if($request->isJson()){
           //TODO: 
           $data = $request->json()->all();

           $user = \DB::table('tabla')->insert(
            [
                'CodigoCliente' => $data['CodigoCliente'],
                'FechaCreacion' => $data['FechaCreacion'],
                'FechaDocumento' => $data['FechaDocumento'],
                'FechaEntrega' => $data['FechaEntrega'],
                'Observaciones' => $data['Observaciones'],
                'TipoPago' => $data['TipoPago'],
                'noOrderEcwid' => $data['noOrderEcwid'],
                'EstadoImpEcWid' => $data['EstadoImpEcWid'],
                'Email' => $data['Email'],
                'NombreCliente' => $data['NombreCliente'],
                'countryName' => $data['countryName'],
                'countryCode' => $data['countryCode'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'street' => $data['street'],
                'stateOrProvinceCode' => $data['stateOrProvinceCode'],
                'stateOrProvinceName' => $data['stateOrProvinceName'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],              

            ]
            ); 

        return response()->json($user, 201 ); 

       }else{

        return response()->json(["ERROR" => "No Autorizado"],200); 
       }
```

Comment: Esto es una pregunta nueva o una edicion a la pregunta?? si es nueva borrala y hace una nueva.. si es una edicion a tu pregunta, borra esta respuesta, y usa el boton editar para agregarlo en tu pregunta...

Comment: Si ya tengo la solución y quiero adjuntar el código de como está, como lo puedo agregar? como  añadir respuesta o editar mi pregunta ?

Comment: @CarlosVanegas ¿es este el código con el que solucionaste el problema? Si sí, simplemente dale a [edit] la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle sobre qué hiciste y cómo funciona. Si no, entonces este código debería ir en la pregunta en sí, y deberías crear una nueva respuesta con la información de la solución. Dinos si necesitas algo y podemos ayudarte con las ediciones. Un saludo.